# Android , How to access SharePoint data?

Tags: android, azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Basically , I wanted the files in my Company Sharepoint after reading documents provide by microsoft. By using Microsoft Graph authentication API I be able to receive `authenticationResult.accessToken` by following this example https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

After that I request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{Mycompany}.sharepoint.com/drives/{Drives ID}/list/items`

the response is all the items in that drives.

**But**

I want to get specific file to display in my application by add item ID

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{Mycompany}.sharepoint.com/drives/{Drives ID}/list/items/{Item ID}`

I got this error

```
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-02-03T04:57:08",
      "request-id": "65b170a7-b864-470e-a1e5-23be9851dd7a",
      "client-request-id": "65b170a7-b864-470e-a1e5-23be9851dd7a"
    }
  }
}
```

After reading through some Document to find out what wrong with it I'm start to confused with it. Some Document using `https://{{tenantName}}.sharepoint.com/Sites.Read.All` without using Graph API
example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom)
but this didn't work out for me. Can you guys guide me how this is all work? and how to receive folder and document in Sharepoint

**Note**
I'm not an expert in Android and new to this kind of stuff.

thank you

Comment: The above error is because there is no access token when you were calling the Graph API call. Make sure you pass the header with the HTTP call having access token in Authorization parameter.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I'm already pass header with token. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{Mycompany}.sharepoint.com/drives/{Drives ID}/list/items` very thing work fine but when I add a **Item ID** it got an error

Comment: Have you checked it in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Yep

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: I believe its not the same error.

Comment: Try this way `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/lists/104bd7b0-2083-4a0a-ad33-18e69603a2f0/items/1` it should work.

Comment: Yes i would suggest you to see what @ShivaKeshavVarma way and see if it helps. In case if it doesnt work its worth to check your token in https://jwt.ms and its values.

Comment: Thank you so much guys after checking my Token in (jwt.ms) I be able to fix the problem

Comment: Glad to here that it worked for you. Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error is because there is no access token when you were calling the Graph API call. Make sure you pass the header with the HTTP call having access token in Authorization parameter. As suggested by @Dev you can also check in https://jwt.ms and see the access token claims. You can also try the below HTTP call.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items/{itemid}`

in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and you could find the difference.